# How can I make a templated function that takes a parameter that is the result of boost::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I have a helper method that takes as input a `boost::function<>` type object and wraps the function with another functor that handles some other logistics.

Here is what my signature looks like:

```
class Example {
public:
    typedef ... Callback;

    ...

    template<typename T>
    static Callback make_wrapper( const boost::function<void( T )>& );
};
```

If I try to pass make_wrapper the result of calling `boost::bind` inline I get compilation errors about types being incompatible (Apple LLVM version 7.3.0)

```
class OtherClass {
public:
    void method ( uint32_t );
};

OtherClass* other;

Example::Callback c = Example::make_wrapper ( boost::bind( &OtherClass::method, other, _1 ) );
```

this gives:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'make_wrapper'
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function' against 'bind_t'
```

I have found 2 ways around this:

1. Temp variable:

   ```
   boost::function<void( uint32_t )> f = boost::bind( &OtherClass::method, other, _1 );
   Example::Callback c = Example::make_wrapper ( f );
   ```
2. Call specific specialization of make_wrapper:

   ```
   Example::Callback c = Example::make_wrapper<uint32_t> ( boost::bind( &OtherClass::method, other, _1 ) );
   ```

I would much prefer it if I could skip the extra hinting and call make_wrapper with the inline call to bind.

Is there a way that I can declare the signature of the make_wrapper template to help the compiler figure out the type without needing to use one of workarounds above?

Comment: Use `auto` or `decltype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use `bind` you discard all information about the bound function's parameter types. A function template can't possibly deduce the parameter type `T`, because the return value of `bind` is a function object that can be called with any number of parameters of any types.

You could wrap the `bind` function into helper function template to deduce the bound member function and especially its result type and parameters (example uses `std::bind` and `std::function` but I believe it can be easily transformed to `boost`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
  void bar(int a, std::string s) {
     std::cout << a << " " << s << std::endl;
  }
};


template<typename T1, typename T2>
void make_wrapper(const std::function<void( T1, T2 )>&) {
}

template <class Foo, class Res, class... Args, class... Placeholders>
std::function<Res(Args...)> my_bind(Res (Foo::*bar)(Args...), Foo& f, Placeholders... ps) {
   return std::bind(bar, f, ps...);
}

int main() {
  foo f;
  make_wrapper(my_bind(&foo::bar, f, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

The code will work as long as `foo::bar` is not overloaded in which case you can't avoid `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.interface.synopsys) list the return type as unspecified. This means you simply cannot know that, if you want to be at all portable.